# Boto3: upload file from base64 to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

How can I directly upload a base64 encoded file to S3 with boto3?

```
object = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME,email+"/"+save_name)
object.put(Body=base64.b64decode(file))
```

I tried to upload the base64 encoded file like this, but then the file is broken. Directly uploading the string without the base64 decoding also doesn't work.

Is there anything similar to `set_contents_from_string()` from boto2?

Comment: what is the stacktrace !?

Comment: what is Object here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed the problem and found out that the way of uploading was correct, but the base64 string was incorrect because it still contained the prefix `data:image/jpeg;base64,` - removing that prefix solved the problem.

Comment: Full code example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58518579/9931092

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation thoughtfully on [Object.put](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put), you will see this

```
response = object.put(
    ACL='private'......,
    Body=b'bytes'|file,
    .....,
```

Body only accept **file object or bytes**, any other type will failed. base64.b64decode doesn't read file object automatically, you must read the data into the decode module.

```
# FIX 
object.put(Body=base64.b64decode(file.read()))
```

As reminder, always post the stacktrace.