# Upload Base64 Image to S3 and return URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload a base64 image to an S3 bucket using Python.
I have googled and got a few answers but none of them works for me. And some answers use boto and not boto3, hence they are useless to me.
I have also tried this link: [Boto3: upload file from base64 to S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420886/boto3-upload-file-from-base64-to-s3) but it is not working for me as `Object` method is unknown to the s3.

Following is my code so far:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
filename = photo.personId + '.png'
bucket_name = 'photos-collection'
dataToPutInS3 = base64.b64decode(photo.url[23:])
```

What is the correct way to upload this variable `dataToPutInS3` data to s3 bucket and get a url back from it?

Comment: The reason why you don't have `s3.Object` is that you use `boto3.client('s3')` and not the `boto3.resource('s3')` as in the example.

Comment: @dmigo Thanks for pointing that up as well, I updated my answer with your input.

Comment: @Karan Sharma did it worked for you?

Comment: Hi @AmitBaranes I have used the code however, I am getting following error while putting object in S3 Bucket:  "reason": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketLocation operation: Access Denied"

Earlier I was getting same Access Denied error for putObject, but after updating iamRoleStatements: for putObject, that error is solved. 

Do you have any idea, how to solve GetBucketLocation Access Denied issue. ?

Comment: Update your iam role actions with this `s3:GetBucketLocation`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't mention how do you get the base64. In order to reproduce,my code snippet getting the image from the internet using the [`requests`](https://realpython.com/python-requests/) library and later convert it to base64 using the [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) library.

The trick here is to make sure the base64 string you want to upload doesn't include the `data:image/jpeg;base64` prefix.
And, as @dmigo mentioned in the comments, you should work with [**boto3.resource**](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html) and not boto3.client.

```py
    from botocore.vendored import requests
    import base64
    import boto3

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket_name = 'BukcetName'
    #where the file will be uploaded, if you want to upload the file to folder use 'Folder Name/FileName.jpeg'
    file_name_with_extention = 'FileName.jpeg'
    url_to_download = 'URL'

    #make sure there is no data:image/jpeg;base64 in the string that returns
    def get_as_base64(url):
        return base64.b64encode(requests.get(url).content)

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        image_base64 = get_as_base64(url_to_download)
        obj = s3.Object(bucket_name,file_name_with_extention)
        obj.put(Body=base64.b64decode(image_base64))
        #get bucket location
        location = boto3.client('s3').get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_name)['LocationConstraint']
        #get object url
        object_url = "https://%s.s3-%s.amazonaws.com/%s" % (bucket_name,location, file_name_with_extention)
        print(object_url)
```

More about [S3.Object.put](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put).

Comment: I get the base64 image string data from the Web App, The function post_guest_photo receives the image data and then I have to save that image as jpeg to an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 13):

You can convert your base64 to IO Bytes and use `upload_fileobj` to upload to S3 bucket.

```py
import base64
import six
import uuid
import imghdr
import io


def get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file):
    extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
    extension = "jpg" if extension == "jpeg" else extension
    return extension


def decode_base64_file(data):
    """
    Fuction to convert base 64 to readable IO bytes and auto-generate file name with extension
    :param data: base64 file input
    :return: tuple containing IO bytes file and filename
    """
    # Check if this is a base64 string
    if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
        # Check if the base64 string is in the "data:" format
        if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
            # Break out the header from the base64 content
            header, data = data.split(';base64,')

        # Try to decode the file. Return validation error if it fails.
        try:
            decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
        except TypeError:
            TypeError('invalid_image')

        # Generate file name:
        file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12]  # 12 characters are more than enough.
        # Get the file name extension:
        file_extension = get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file)

        complete_file_name = "%s.%s" % (file_name, file_extension,)

        return io.BytesIO(decoded_file), complete_file_name


def upload_base64_file(base64_file):
    bucket_name = 'your_bucket_name'
    file, file_name = decode_base64_file(base64_file)
    client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='aws_access_key_id',
                          aws_secret_access_key='aws_secret_access_key')

    client.upload_fileobj(
        file,
        bucket_name,
        file_name,
        ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'}
    )
    return f"https://{bucket_name}.s3.amazonaws.com/{file_name}"
```

Comment: Best answer !! Works like a charm

Comment: can you please help me on where to use this function in the code, I have a similar question in here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72139962/need-to-override-save-method-for-image-field-and-save-it-as-base64-string-using.