# How to upload a base64 encoding string as an image to S3 using AWS Lambda [NodeJS]

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an aws lambda function in which I recieve a String which is Base64 encoded version of a Bitmap. How can I upload it as a .png file to an S3 bucket ? I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58518579/9931092

Answer (score 0):

Decode the base64 string into bytes, and use bytes as the body to upload to S3.