# Need to override save method for image field and save it as base64 string using django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-models, django-rest-framework, base64

**models.py**

```
class Organisation(models.Model):

    org_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    org_name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=100)
    org_code = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=20)
    org_mail_id = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    org_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    org_address = models.JSONField(max_length=500, null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='products')
    org_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_org_logo, null=True, blank=True,)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I need to save an image which I get in image field on org_logo as a base64 string and upload it to the s3 bucket which I have given as file storage using django storages.
**Note**: File object will be the input I will be getting from the frontend(React). I need to override the save method to save it as base64 string.

I have referred many data but I couldn't able to get it properly. Can anyone please guide me to what exactly needs to be changed and where so that I could understand better.

Answer (score 0):

```
import base64
image = open(form.cleaned_data['image'], 'rb')
image_read = image.read()
image_64_encode = base64.encodebytes(image_read)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: @rajeel where I should use this mathod in my code. In my models or serializers or in the views? and the image refers here is the image field name ?

Comment: can anyone please help me on implementing this, I am not still clear how and where to use this?, as I am rookie to django.